# Get the dates of a custom post types taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, date

This is my code. This only brings up the word Date with actual numbers. I need to get the custom post type 'resource' taxonomy `'sermon'`. Any suggestions.Basically I need to get a sepcific custom post types(resource) taxonmy(sermon) dates.  I a trying to get the dates for a custom post type. the custom post type has a taxonomy so i need the dates of that taxonomy..
In this case the custom post type is resouces and the taxonomy is sermon

This is my code:

```
<?php
        $argp = array( 'post_type' => 'resource' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $argp );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
              $dates[] = get_the_date();
                $dates = array_unique($dates);

               endwhile;  
               ?>
               <select name="ddate" id="ddate" class="styled-select">
               <option value="#">Date</option>
               <?php
               foreach($dates as $date) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $date . '">' . $date .'</option> ';
                  }
              ?>
              </select>
```

Comment: can u elaborate what u need exactly?

Comment: Hi Gropal.. I a trying to get the dates for a custom post type. the custom post type has a taxonomy so i need the dates of that taxonomy.. I hope this is more clear..

Comment: there is no such fields for 'date' for taxonomy. You can check it in your database.